# How to add external framework / Library in cocoa framework in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift2

In my project I have multiple components / Modules (cocoa framework)
in particular, I need to add some additional external framework like "image cache".

I am able to add in main target, But how can i add into particular target?

More explanation,
I have multiple target in my project. I like to add external framework for particular target not for all in swift 2.0.

Comment: No, My question is not about how to add a framework in project.
below is my question,
I have multiple target in my project. I like to add external framework for particular target not for all in swift 2.0.